# jQuery droppable on dynamic input fields

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-droppable

I've been pulling my hair on how to get the jquery droppable function to work with dynamcially generated input fields but I have not succeeded so far. I have read a few articles suggesting to use the .live() function but I am not sure how to get it to work.

I am relatively new to JavaScript and any help will be much appreciated.

You can see the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/kWAtJ/151/

What I am trying to do is, drap and drop the <li>iPad</li> text into the dynamically created textareas. It works fine on the first textarea but not on the dynamically generated one.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is your updated FIDDLE

http://jsfiddle.net/5rpQt/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I see that you added the initialize() function inside add_field(). The problem is that in my app, I cannot modify the add_field() function. I have to work with a WordPress plugin that dynamically add custom fields and I need to drag and drop content into those custom fields.